# Discord bot sorting

Tags: discord, discord.js

I have limited js knowledge and maybe it is simpler to try and do this through the discord bot?
I want to make a discord bot that would work like a sorting hat from harry potter.

My discord server is having a house/faction system and I need a bot to create a personality quiz so that depending on what they answer, they will gain a role of the house they've been placed in.
Each answer to a question will be weighted towards one of the three houses.
EXAMPLE:
H1 equals House 1, H2 equals House 2, H3 equals House 3

What is the most important in your life?

1. success +1 H1
2. friendsandfamily +1 H2
3. change +1 H3

Once all questions are answered, the most points for a house would be where the user ends up in and gets a role.
How the questions and answers should be displayed would look a little like this, where the question and answers would come up in the little menu while answering them would be to react a discord emoji shown below it.

Comment: Could you include an image example? I'm still confused where you need help on.

Answer (score 0):

I can give you a flow of whats supposed to happen, but I don't really want to spoon feed you ok?

First, you send a message embed. You can use something like [this](https://leovoel.github.io/embed-visualizer/) to visualize an embed that you are making, then use [this](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/embeds.html#embeds) guide to create an actual embed & send it. Then, you can use discordjs.guide's guide on reactions, in specific [adding ones](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-to-messages) ([ordering them](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#reacting-in-order)) and [awaiting ones](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/reactions.html#awaiting-reactions).

After receiving a reaction, you can then figure out which one, (`reaction.emoji.name`), and then based on that add to an object, which would be something like

```js
let UserHouses = {
    H1: 0,
    H2: 0,
    H3: 0
};
//upon receiving a reaction and sorting through it, you simply
UserHouses.H1 += weight
```